# Need to fix the Navigation CSS issue?

Tags: css

I want to show bold current menu item only, but if I am trying to bold current menu item, the sub menu items are also getting bold.

my CSS is:

```
.main .current-item{
    font-weight:900;
}
```

I want to get bold only current menu item which is Second and class is current-item

```
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li class="current-item">
        <a href="#">Second</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Inner First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inner Second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply it to the immediate child anchor only:

```
.main .current-item > a {
    font-weight:900;
}
```

[More information about the direct descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Almost right, you'll have to address the actual `<a>` inside the `<li class="current-item">` to style it.

```
.main .current-item > a {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Roberrrt for quick reply but as you can see .current-item is the class of li and that li is a parent for .sub-meu so all the li in .current-item class and also a in .sub-menu class will get bolder.

Comment: Yeah, I failed to provide the `>` Pete already did, which is indeed the one that styles the _direct child_ of `.current-item`